# OpenAPI documentation for External API in Spring Boot 3 project

Tags: java, spring-boot, openapi

I am using Spring Boot 3 and using OpenAPI by having this in the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Using HttpExchange interface, as per https://www.baeldung.com/spring-6-http-interface, I have created the interface to call external APIs.

How can I make use of OpenAPI to generate a documentation of the external API with the HttpExchange interface?